# How do I manage stream buffering?

Tags: roku

I have a few questions about buffering and how to manage it.
At this moment I have a roku channel that streams both, mkv and mp4 files, as well as hls live streams.

When I test the channel with 50 Mbps it works well, but with slower internet connections (5 - 12 Mbps) it buffers a lot and I didn't find any information on how to manage this.

For the live stream I'm using a custom player using the roVideoPlayer, feeding it with and a list of live stream links. Apperently when it loses connection it skips to the next item on the list, and what I want to do is to rebuffer the current channel even if the connection is slow.

Now for the mkv and mp4 I'm using the roVideoScreen, the problem is that with HD content (more than 420) it buffers a alot, and I would like to buffer only once even if it takes longer.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *streams* attribute in place of *stream* to set the contentList or ContentItem. In the streams attribute you can set the array of associative array with the differenet stream urls of different bitrate for same video.

for further details follow the following link

http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Content+Meta-Data

Hope this will help.